# Proving differentiability at a point c

Tags: derivatives

Let $c \  \epsilon \ \mathbb R$. Suppose $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is differentiable at all points $x \notin \ c$ and that the limits of $f'(x)$ as $x \rightarrow c^+$ and $x \rightarrow c^-$ both equal $L$. Then, $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and $f'(c) = L$.

This sounds false, but why would I have to prove it as the prompt asks if it says $f$ is differentiable at all points $x$ but $c$, then it claims "then, $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and $f'(c) = L$"

Comment: Maybe it should be reworded as "assume you know $f$ is differentiable everywhere except possibly at $c$ etc..."

Comment: You *assume* $f$ is continuous everywhere except at $c$. This does not mean $f$ is not continuous at $c$, just that you don't know if it is or it isn't. And then based on other assumptions, you must show it is differentiable at $c$.